# Setting ownership and permissions to an ntfs usb drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, ntfs

I have a seagate backup plus HD.  2 TB, usb.

When I plug in the drive Ubuntu auto mounts it to /media/me/myhd.
Here is the myhd directory after being mounted.

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root 524288 Dec 31  1969 myhd/
```

When I try to change the ownership:

```
chown: changing ownership of 'myhd': Operation not permitted
```

When I try to change the permissions:

```
me@xps:/media/ian$ sudo chmod 744 /media/me/myhd
me@xps:/media/ian$ ll
total 520
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 me  me    4096 Jun 30 22:36 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Jun 30 22:22 ../
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root 524288 Dec 31  1969 myhd/
```

My goal is to be able to manage permissions and ownership of my hard drive.
I am trying to install a plex server and the server is up and running but it shows nothing in my Library.  I believe the permissions are the problem.
Please.  Any help right now would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

Comment: First thing I tried.  Didn't work.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: the "correct" answer in @muru's link isn't the accepted answer but the one from JanC. Not that there are **two** different NTFS drivers on Linux: pure kernel ntfs (limited), and fuse-based ntfs-3g. You need ntfs-3g in use and option -o permissions

Comment: The plex user is in both my group and the root group .  If my group and user have access to read and write, shouldn't the plex user be able to do the same?